# Use of a boolean flag inside django 1.9 (template)

Tags: django

I have the following database models (truncated):

```
class Enzymes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Enzymes'
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Activitydiagram(models.Model):
    enzymes = models.ForeignKey(Enzymes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Spectraimage(models.Model):
    enzymes = models.ForeignKey(Enzymes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activitydiagram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I am trying to make it so that on my webpage, it shows the data in blocks. Specifically that it shows the spectraimage(s) under the corresponding activity diagram, followed by any 'unassigned' spectraimages as follows:

- Activitydiagram x1

  - Spectraimage y1
  - Spectraimage y2
- Activitydigram x2

  - Spectraimage y3
- Spectraimage y4 (that belongs to the enzyme but doesn't have a matching activity diagram)

I got most of the desired behaviour working except, getting the`y4` spectraimage to show apart from the rest. I was looking into using a boolean flag where in my `html` file I would do something like this (Notice the bits between ##):

views.py

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'gts/detail.html'
    model = Enzymes

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        enzyme = context['object']
        activities = Activitydiagram.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
        spectras = Spectraimage.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
        context['activities'] = activities
        context['spectras'] = spectras
        return context
```

details.html

```
  {% if activities %}
    <hr/>
    <h3>
      Activity Diagram
    </h3>
    <br/>
    {% for activity in activities %}
      <img class="img-responsive" src="/{{activity.activity_image}}" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
      <br/>
      {% if spectras %}
        ## Initialize a flag to 0 ##
        {% for spectra in spectras %}
          {% if activity.id == spectra.activity_id %}
            ## Set a flag to 1 ##
            <hr/>
            <h3>
              Chromatogram(s) (belonging to above activity diagram)
            </h3>
            <br/>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for spectra in spectras %}
          {% if activity.id == spectra.activity_id %}
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/{{spectra.spectra_image}}" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        ## if flag == 0, do other logic ##
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

However, from my limited experience with Django and looking at similar problems I feel that this is not the way that this issue should be handled (by seperating logic from presentation). Therefore, how should one handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much logic in the template. You can't assign variables as your comment `## Set a flag to 1 ##` suggests.

In your view, create two querysets. One of all the activities, and one for the spectra *without* an activity.

```
activities = Activitydiagram.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
spectras_without_activities = Spectraimage.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme, activity=None)
```

Then, in your template, loop through the activities, and use the reverse relation to get the related spectra for each activity.

```
{% for activity in activities %}
    {{ activity }}
    {% for spectra in activity.spectraimage_set.all %}
        {{ spectra }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

At the end, you can loop through your spectra which do not have a related activity.

```
{% for spectra in spectras_without_activities %}
    {{ spectra }}
{% endfor %}
```

The code above assumes that `spectra.enzyme == activity.enzyme` for every spectra in `activity.spectraimage_set.all`. If that's not the case, you'll have to add an additional check.

Once you've got it working, you optimise the query by using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch the related spectras at the same time as the activities.

Comment: I thought as much (the too much logic part) while I was writing it. I hadn't considered making two querysets, great idea!